# #DIV/0! error in pivot table calculated field when values exist

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

The calculated field works fine in monthly total, but displays an error in the grand total.

It should show 7.8% from 373,908 divided by 4,778,270.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That isn't how the field is calculated. It uses values from the column, `Total Sum of Field2`. Since there are `#DIV/0!` errors, it will not calculate as you desire. If you want additional help, it would be beneficial if we could examine the source data to determine if there are any steps that can be taken to improve the results.

Comment: It is the total result not the filed value.